# Steps of creating appid for bing search

Tags: bing-api

I am really stuck with the bing search Api. In bing's developer centre I do not find any option to generating Appid. Actually I want to used the bing's search functionality using curl.

When I try to hit the Api it displayed the following error :

computer test2001AppID is not functioning properly. Please refer to the HelpUrl to get more information.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251042.aspx

Array
(
    [SearchResponse] => Array
        (
            [Query] => Array
                (
                    [SearchTerms] => computer test
                )

```
        [Errors] => Array
            (
                [Error] => Array
                    (
                        [Code] => 2001
                        [Message] => AppID is not functioning properly. Please refer to the HelpUrl to get more information.
                        [HelpUrl] => http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251042.aspx
                    )

            )

    )

[SearchResponse_attr] => Array
    (
        [xmlns] => http://schemas.microsoft.com/LiveSearch/2008/04/XML/element
        [Version] => 2.0
    )
```

)

Please help me. I think its a wrong Appid error message So please tell me the steps of generating the new Appid I do not find any option on developer's centre.

Big Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this same problem when I got started. Microsoft no longer lets you add app IDs without submitted an app on the Azure Marketplace. They now use a security key that acts as both your username and password.

5000 queries/month are free -> http://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/search.

Read this guide to migrating from the old API style to the new one -> http://www.bing.com/webmaster/content/developers/ADM_MIGRATION_GUIDE.docx

Comment: Great answer!!! I searched a lot for something like it, since Microsoft documentation is outdated...