# Bing API error 1002

Tags: java

First of all I'm sorry for my English.
I am developing an application in java and I want to use search Bing API, So I opened user-centered development of Bing (http://www.bing.com/dev/en-us/dev-center) and accept key number then I wrote the following code to get results Bing

```
String q = "http://api.bing.net/json.aspx?Appid=MyClientId=girls&sources=web&web.count=40&web.offset=41";

URL searchURL;
try {
    searchURL = new URL(q);
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) searchURL.openConnection();

    if(httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader, 8192);

        String line = null;
        String result = "";
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            result += line;
        }

        bufferedReader.close();
    }
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Why do I get the following error 1002?

```
{"SearchResponse":{
    "Version":"2.2",
    "Query":{"SearchTerms":"girls"},
    "Errors":[
        {"Code":1002,
         "Message":"Parameter has invalid value.",
         "Parameter":"SearchRequest.AppId",
         "Value":"MyClientId",
         "HelpUrl":"http:\/\/msdn.microsoft.com\/en-us\/library\/dd251042.aspx"}]
}}
```

Comment: Next time when pasting data, try to make the code and other snippets **readable** ;)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got a typo in the address
This looks very suspicious:

```
Appid=MyClientId=girls
```

You should see the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd250882.aspx, but I guess that you need to replace the `MyClientId` with something and also you haven't spearated the query and the clientId i.e. `&q=girls`

EDIT: You need to get the AppId somewhere [Steps of creating appid for bing search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795396/steps-of-creating-appid-for-bing-search)

Here's some question which can help you:
[Bing search API and Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844463/bing-search-api-and-azure/10844666#10844666)

Comment: First of all thanks for the quick response
I fixed the problem of Appid = MyClientId = girls but it's still not working
I read the documentation but I could not figure out where I put the key in url address by documentation
Thanks again for the help